# Calling method from within itself?

Tags: java, recursion, methods

ok so i have a method that displays a menu and returns the user selection.

```
public class Menu {


public static int menuSelect(){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Hello, Please Select A Function: ");
System.out.println("1) Sort All Banks Alphabetically ");
System.out.println("2) Calculate Interest And Show Balance ");
System.out.println("3) Transfer Money ");
System.out.println("4) Calulate Sum & Average Of All Accounts: ");
System.out.println("5) Richest Account: ");
System.out.println("6) Poorest Account: ");

int select = input.nextInt();

Menu.menuSelect();

 //i tried this as adding Menu.menuSelect(); 
 //after the return threw an error.
 // but surprise suprise this doesnt actually 
//let the method return anythign to select

  return select;
}
```

The idea is that i want menu to come up the user selects a function, the function happens and then the menu calls itself until told otherwise.
but im unsure how to do this.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have an infinite recursion here. Why not use a while loop?

Comment: i like the idea of doing it this way lol.

Comment: Then get used to StackOverflowException.

Comment: *You surely can't do everything you like*.... like having a never ending recursion and expecting it to end or do something else

Comment: no no the idea was that i would add an option like exit which would system.exit(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the same method from itself is called a [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), and it's infinite in your case. You obviously don't need it here.

You want to have something like this:

```
private static int getInput() {
    int choice = menuSelect();
    while(choice < 1 || choice > 6) {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice, please re-enter")
        choice = menuSelect();
    }
    return choice;
}
```

Note that it's bad to give `menuSelect` a `public` *modifier*, you don't want anyone outside the class to have an access to it.

Comment: just trying to understand this code, is this outside the menuSelect method?